# Dynamically change the size of devexpress tileBar-Control items

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I started working with the tilebar-control, and I saw that the documentation on this topic is quite small.
Usually, my Controls (inside a 'Layout-Control') are changing their sizes when you resize the form, but the groups with their items inside the tileBar are staying as big as before.

How do I change the setting, that the groups resize automatically?
The Control itself gets bigger/smaller, but only the frame is what changes.

edit:

Another Possibility would be to disable the resizing of the tileBar. But I can't find that setting either.

Comment: Kindly provide a same of your code so we may identify the parts that need changes.

Comment: Check it out here > https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q395511

Comment: There's no code yet, I did everything in the designer